# Pointer null check evaluates to true even though it is not assigned a null value

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree

This is a code for creating a binary tree, and it is executing perfectly. What I don't understand is how `temp->left==NULL` or `temp->right==NULL` conditions for the `if()` statements inside the `insert(string)` function are getting evaluated to `TRUE` when, in my opinion, it should be throwing a segmentation fault since nowhere have I initialized the `left` or `right` pointers of a node to `NULL`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
  public:
    string data;
    node *left,*right;
};

class btree
{
  private:
    node *root;

  public:
    btree()
    {
      root=NULL;
    }
    void create();
    void insert(string);
};

void btree:: create()
{
  cout<<"\n\nEnter the no. of nodes you want to create: ";
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  cin.ignore();
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cout<<"\nEnter data for node "<<i+1<<": ";
    string input;
    getline(cin,input);
    insert(input);
  }
}

void btree:: insert(string str)
{
  if(root==NULL)
  {
    root=new node;
    root->data=str;
    return;
  }
  node *temp=root;
  while(temp!=NULL)
  {
    cout<<"\n\nDo you want to enter the node in the left subtree or the right subtree of "<<temp->data<<"?(l/r): ";
    char dir;
    cin>>dir;
    cin.ignore();
    if(dir=='l')
    {
      if(temp->left==NULL)
      {
        temp->left=new node;
        temp->left->data=str;
        return;
      }
      else
        temp=temp->left;
    }
    if(dir=='r')
    {
      if(temp->right==NULL)
      {
        temp->right=new node;
        temp->right->data=str;
        return;
      }
      else
        temp=temp->right;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  btree bt;
  bt.create();

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter the no. of nodes you want to create: 3

Enter data for node 1: 5

Enter data for node 2: 1


Do you want to enter the node in the left subtree or the right subtree of 5?(l/r): l

Enter data for node 3: 9


Do you want to enter the node in the left subtree or the right subtree of 5?(l/r): r
```

To check whether this is indeed just UB or an effect of the `new` operator I ran a test code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
  public:
    int data;
    node *left,*right;
};

int main()
{
  node *root=new node;
  root=NULL;
  cout<<"\nroot = "<<root; //This cout is executed since root has been initialized to NULL 
  std::cout.flush();
  cout<<"\nroot->left = "<<root->left; //This line immediately throws segmentation fault
  std::cout.flush();

  return 0;
}
```

Output of the test code:

```
root = 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So the test code seems to recognise UB and throws segfault. Why not the first code?

I tried searching for a similar question but couldn't find one.

Comment: _"... since nowhere have I initialized ..."_: Undefined Behaviour includes appearing to work (probably __by chance__ getting memory with/initialised to 0).

Comment: @RichardCritten: I don't think this is undefined behaviour as that condition is checked multiple times in the code but it never generates an error. I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: __At I guess__: the memory allocator you are using (what `new` calls) is initialising new memory to all `0`s.

Comment: The behavior of UB is **undefined** - a segfault is only one possible outcome, your test proves nothing

Comment: @UnholySheep: Does this mean that _every_ time I run the code, I am simply getting lucky and that `temp->left` and `temp->right` are being set to NULL which causes my code to run correctly?

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. Maybe the memory allocator is setting everything to 0 as Richard Critten noted. It could also be your compiler initializing pointers to null to help you debug. Or it could just be pure luck that the memory happened to be 0. That's just the way undefined behavior works. You can get a crash, but the program can also appear to work, or you get very weird results due to compiler optimizations. Literally, anything can happen, and there is no such thing as "recognizing" UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **explicitly** initialise `left` and `right` to `NULL`, `0`, or `nullptr` (preferrably `nullptr`). As mentioned by other commenters, there is a high possibility of experiencing undefined behaviour when the pointer is not initialised.

Best practice (IMHO):

```
class node
{
  public:
    string data;
    node *left = nullptr;
    node *right = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: But that's exactly my point! I _never_ initialized those pointers to NULL and still the null check evaluates to TRUE and the rest of the code is executed. Why does it not throw an error?

Comment: It's like an uninitialised `int`. The compiler won't generate an error. We need to make sure it's either initialised or that it won't be used immediately as an r-value.

Comment: @shaun022 If you don't initialize a variable (pointer or otherwise) it has an *indeterminate* value. You may *read* such a value, but *using* it for anything (like in a comparison) is Undefined Behaviour. UB means your program has no meaning according to the standard and the compiler is allowed to do *whatever it wants* and no, it is *not* required to generate warnings or errors.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I would like to think that this is UB. But I have run this code many times over and everytime it executes successfully. I have also added a test code in my question which immediately gives segmentation fault while trying to access uninitialized pointer. So I don't understand why the first code doesn't throw errors.

Comment: @shaun022 Undefined Behaviour is *undefined*. It may manifest as your code doing nothing at all. Crashing. Doing exactly what you expect or *anything* else. That you tested it and observed a specific result means nothing - it's still undefined and a different compiler (or different compiler version), different optimization level  or different platform or unrelated changes to other parts of your program can lead to the observed behaviour changing.

Comment: Well, seeing that every feedback I have got suggests it could be undefined behaviour, though a very peculiar one for me, I am accepting this answer since it suggests doing away with the source of the problem.